# C#- background worker's CancelAsync() not working?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I want to abort the process but not able to do so, I am using Background worker with my functions of processing.

```
public void Init()
{
    bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
}

void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (bw.CancellationPending == true)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Result = abd();
    }
}

void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Cancelled)
    {
        lbltext.content="Canceled";
    }

    else
    {
        lbltext.content="Completed";
    }
}

private void btncan_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bw.CancelAsync();
}

private void btnstart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

I am not able to abort the process using this code.
Function `abd()` is performing the processing part and returning the result.

Please provide me any solution.

Thanks.

Comment: And where is the process? You have some loop in DoWork method? Currently backgroundworker finishes it's work before you click button

Comment: and please format your code nicely :)

Comment: isn't the background worker aborted when the main thread is terminated?

Comment: I think you have to check more than once, to cancel the async running background-worker...

Comment: function abd() is performing processing and returning the result

Comment: @neelb2 `abd()` is a long-running operation, which you call in background? Does this operation supports cancellation?

Comment: Side note: Your completed handler should also check `e.Error`.

Answer (score 18):

When you call `bw.CancelAsync()` you just set `CancellationPending` flag to `true`. It does not cancels something by default. You need to handle pending cancellation manually. But you can't do that with your code, because when you click button, there are three possible options:

- Long-running `abd()` method finished it's work and there is nothing to cancel
- `abd()` started it's work, and background worker is blocked - it's waiting for results of `abd()`, then it continues execution - i.e. exits `if-else` block and raises `RunWorkerCompleted` event.
- Nearly impossible option - you will be fast as light, and you will click button before `if-else` block entered. Than `CancellationPending` will be true, and `abd()` will not start execution

---

If you want to use cancellation, then do your long-running task in a loop, and check if cancellation is pending on each step:

```
void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    List<Foo> results = new List<Foo>();

    // any loop here - foreach, while
    for(int i = 0; i < steps_count; i++)
    {    
         // check status on each step
         if (bw.CancellationPending == true) 
         {
             e.Cancel = true;
             return; // abort work, if it's cancelled
         }

         results.Add(abd()); // add part of results
    }

    e.Result = results; // return all results
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it is also not working properly as i have tested it with 2 step loop. when i am aborting it after starting it is not getting aborted but it is stopping the next step to be executed. so if you have any further solution so let know.

Comment: @neelb2 yes, that's how it supposed to work - current step will be executed, further steps will be cancelled

Comment: I just to interrupt it in between the process either pause or stop.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `DoWork` may have finished its work before calling `CancelAsync` and as mentioned in the docs `e.Cancelled` may be false..

[Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx) say this

> Be aware that your code in the DoWork event handler may finish its
>   work as a cancellation request is being made, and your polling loop
>   may miss CancellationPending being set to true. In this case, the
>   Cancelled flag of System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs in
>   your RunWorkerCompleted event handler will not be set to true, even
>   though a cancellation request was made. This situation is called a
>   race condition and is a common concern in multithreaded programming.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
While(!bw.CancellationPending)
{
   //do some work!
}
e.Cancel = true;
```